# Does the Creality Ender-3 v2 come with a threaded rod or a lead screw?

Tags: creality-ender-3

For the benefit of a novice friend who wants to get into 3D printing, I am following an excellent YouTube course by [Paul McWhorter](https://www.youtube.com/@paulmcwhorter), on Fusion 360 ([playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4rvteV-L8s&list=PLGs0VKk2DiYwxUjGRWEgotTY8ipVvFsIp)) which uses a Creality Ender-3 v2 to process the resulting designs.

However, the esteemed Mr McWhorter often refers to the "threaded rod" during the video that covers the assembly of the printer ([Fusion 360 for 3D Printing LESSON 2: Assembling the Creality Ender 3 Version 2 3D Printer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_94O7IoiY40)).

Is this just a slip of the tongue, or does the Ender-3 v2 actually come with a threaded rod, and *not* a lead screw?

Looking at the official dual Z-axis upgrade kit for the Ender-3 v2 on Amazon, [Creality Official Ender 3 Dual Z-Axis Upgrade Kit ( 42-34 Stepper Motor Included ) for Ender-3, Ender-3S, Ender 3 Pro, Ender 3 V2 3D Printer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Creality-Official-Included-Ender-3S-3D/dp/B09RX4S2MF), it would seem that the kit comes with a lead screw:

[image: Lead screw in the dual Z-axis upgrade kit]

Therefore it would seem logical that the base printer also comes with a lead screw. However, I've not really been able to find a clear enough image of the printer's component parts in order to ascertain whether that is true or not.

I don't want to recommend that my friend purchases an Ender-3 v2, only to realise that it is supplied with a threaded rod, when it arrives.

Can anyone, who either owns an Ender-3 v2, or who has seen one "in-the-flesh", confirm whether it comes with a lead screw?

Also, without wishing to broaden the scope of this question, do *all* Creality printers come with lead screws? Are there any Creality printer models that do actually come with a dreaded threaded rod (which, IMHO, should be avoided, as that would require an immediate upgrade to lead screw)?

Note: I'm not looking for a (shopping) recommendation, I just need a simple yes or no confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ender 3 v2 does have a lead screw.

[image: Photo of lead screw on Ender 3 v2]

These are the main differences:

- Threaded rods have a single V-shaped thread
- Lead screws have multiple trapezoidal threads

Comment: Another significant difference in the pictured lead screw is that it is a multi-lead thread. Many lead screws are. Threaded rod is almost universally single lead. An advantage of multi-lead threads is that they make more rapid advance possible at the relatively low rotational speeds of stepper motors.

Comment: Ah, yes. I will add to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: Not square but **trapezoidal*

Comment: The most common thread Americans will have seen like this (aside from the multiple starts) is the Acme thread used in screw jacks for cars.  Acme is a specific bevel angle and major/minor diameter difference per pitch of trapezoidal thread.